# Difference between two time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, adminlte

I am creating an Over time system, where users input there Start time and End time of there OT, my problem is I don't know how to compute hrs rendered of there over time.

Here's **sample** of output:

In this sample user start there OT at 6pm and end at 8pm then the output must be 2 hrs.

[image]

Here's my Code:

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>FROM</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="timeFrom" type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>TO</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="timeTO" type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am currently using time picker of [Adminlte](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html)

Comment: Hello Sir @ssc-hrep3 can you put your solution?

Comment: I've added an example using `moment.js` based on @Karan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.timepicker').timepicker();

function getDiff() {
  var timeFrom = $('#timeFrom').data('timepicker');
  var timeTO = $('#timeTO').data('timepicker');
debugger;
  var timeFromHH = (timeFrom.hour == 12 && timeFrom.meridian == "AM") ? 0 :
    (timeFrom.hour != 12 && timeFrom.meridian == "PM") ? timeFrom.hour + 12 :
    timeFrom.hour;
  var timeTOHH = (timeTO.hour == 12 && timeTO.meridian == "AM") ? 0 :
    (timeTO.hour != 12 && timeTO.meridian == "PM") ? timeTO.hour + 12 :
    timeTO.hour;

  var timeFromMM = timeFromHH * 60 + timeFrom.minute;
  var timeTOMM = timeTOHH * 60 + timeTO.minute;

  var diffMM = Math.abs(timeTOMM - timeFromMM);
  var diff = Math.floor(diffMM / 60) + "hrs " + (diffMM % 60) + "mins";
  
  $("#diff").text(diff);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>FROM</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="timeFrom" type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>TO</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="timeTO" type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="getDiff()">Get Diff</button>
<label id="diff"></label>
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Karan I appreciate your help, what is the use of timeTOHH  I think its unused.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using the duration and date parsing features of [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com), based on the answer of [@Karan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319114/3233827). You could also directly use the generated string as an input to the moment.js parsing function.

```js
$('.timepicker').timepicker();

function getDiff() {
  var from = moment(getTimeString($('#timeFrom').data('timepicker')), 'HH:mm A');
  var to = moment(getTimeString($('#timeTO').data('timepicker')), 'HH:mm A');

  var diff = to.diff(from, 'minutes');
  $("#diff").text(diff + ' minutes');
}

function getTimeString(datePickerObject) {
  return datePickerObject.hour + ':' + datePickerObject.minute + ' ' + datePickerObject.meridian;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>FROM</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="timeFrom" type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>TO</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="timeTO" type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="getDiff()">Get Diff</button>
<label id="diff"></label>
```